# C# "Keyset does not exist" when call Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair

Tags: c#, itext, x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509certificate2

I created a test project in C # windows forms and I integrated the methods to take a document and sign it with the certificate, but when I get to the point of calling `DotNetUtils.GetKeyPair()` it returns **"Keyset does not exist"**. I found that I have to "install" the certificate as "exportable", but isn't there a way to not delete and re-import the certificate? Any way to make it work in the situation I am in now?
This is my code :

```
private byte[] SignDocumentWithCertificate(byte[] myPdf, X509Certificate2 myCertificate)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(myPdf);
            using (MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, msOutput, '\0');

                PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.SignatureAppearance;

                sap.Reason = "Documento firmato con certificato '" + myCertificate.FriendlyName.ToString() + "' .";
                sap.Location = "Italy";

                X509Certificate2 signatureCert = new X509Certificate2(myCertificate);

                var pk = DotNetUtils.GetKeyPair(signatureCert.PrivateKey).Private; //NON FUNZIONA, VA IN EXCEPTION

                BcX509.X509Certificate bcCert = DotNetUtils.FromX509Certificate(signatureCert);
                var chain = new List<BcX509.X509Certificate> { bcCert };

                IExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256");

                MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

                return msOutput.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The certificate can be store in the users temporary storage (IE Settings) area and the key can be extracted when the program runs.  But it has to be added once either manually in the Browser IE settings or by an application.

Comment: As you start with a `X509Certificate2`, have you considered using the `X509Certificate2Signature` class instead of the `PrivateKeySignature` class? You simply instantiate it with your `X509Certificate2` instance and the desired hash algorithm and don't need to extract keys. Beware, though, `X509Certificate2Signature` as is only support DSA and RSA.

Answer (score 0):

@mkl In the end with your suggestion I searched and solved with this code :

```
private byte[] SignDocumentWithCertificate_VCertificate(byte[] myPdf, X509Certificate2 myCertificate)
{
    using (MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfReader Reader = new PdfReader(myPdf);
        PdfStamper Stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(Reader, msOutput, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance SAP = Stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        BcX509.X509Certificate BouncyCertificate = DotNetUtils.FromX509Certificate(myCertificate);
        var chain = new List<BcX509.X509Certificate> { BouncyCertificate };

        IExternalSignature ES = new X509Certificate2Signature(myCertificate, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1);
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(SAP, ES, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        Stamper.Close();
        Reader.Close();
        return msOutput.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I signed the document using the certificate and not the private key.
Thanks a lot.